# I'm creating test automation and I want to resolve exceptions

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenide

If the create product button is inactive, it should not be clicked, and after the code a is executed, the code to click the create button on the entered page is written as follows.

```
CreatorProductPage.createProductButton().shouldNotBe(Condition.disabled).click();
CreatorAddProductPage.createClassButton().click();
```

But here, if I can't find the product creation button in code a, I want to run code b. How should I do that?

Comment: What programming language or framework are you using to create the tests? Are these unit tests or system tests?

Comment: Since I make products manually, I want to make products automatically to reduce resources, so I am making them myself.
I'm working with Java & Selenide.